# Use sort command in a function bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script with a menu thats have diffrent functions in it.

In one function, I want to sort my input file but when I run the script and the function, it leaves the terminal empty.

This is the function:

```
function sort()
{
sort -n $file
}
```

This how I call it from the menu:

```
case $a in
1) sort; menu;;
```

So when i press 1 it just make the terminal empty, If I just write it in the terminal it works.

Comment: Do not create a function with the same name as an existing command or function.  It will ensure you do not mix them up.  Another point, when you press *1*, it will do `sort;`.  Lets assume this calls your function and not the `sort` command.  In your function, you have `sort -n $file`, but you did not specify the value of `$file` so it is sorting  stdin, hence nothing...

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2264) and other common problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort` is calling itself recursively. If you want the function `sort` to call the external command `sort`, you need to use the `command` command to avoid calling the function recursively.

```
sort () {
    command sort -n "$file"
}
```